# Access Violation Reading Location when using imencode()

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2015

I came across a problem when using imencode() function to encode the frame got from my laptop's camera. I am using Visual Studio 2015 with opencv 3.0. Here is the code:

```
cap >> frame;
if(frame.size().width==0) continue;
resize(frame, send, Size(frame.size().width, frame.size().height), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR);
vector < int > compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
compression_params.push_back(jpegqual);

vector < uchar > encoded;   
imencode(".jpg", send, encoded, compression_params);
imshow("send", send);
```

When the code proceeds to imencode() function, the size of vector encoded changes to a meaningless number, e.g. size=-2659404154992 (shown in debug mode). Since I cannot access the implementation of the function, how do I fix it?

Thanks a lot. The code intends to encode the frame and send it to another computer.

Comment: Please check if your compiler is set to Debug and not Release mode.

Comment: @Logman It is in debug mode, if what you mean was whether I ran the program in debug or release.

Answer (score 0):

OK, fine, thanks to @Logman, I tried to use Release mode and it worked. Sorry for bringing such an easy question, but I was so frustrated for it, coz I was thinking about the version of opencv and various of settings of the project.